# Scipy's leastsq with complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, complex-numbers, least-squares

I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.leastsq with complex numbers. I know there are some questions about this already but I still can't get my simple example working, which is complaining about casting from complex to real numbers.

If I did it right the solution to the below should be `x=[1+1j,2j]`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def cost_cpl(x,A,b):
    return np.abs(np.dot(A,x)-b)

A=np.array([[1,1],[2j,0]],dtype=np.complex128)
b=np.array([1+3j,-2+2j],dtype=np.complex128)
x,r=leastsq(cost_cpl,np.array([0+0j,0+0j]),args=(A,b))
print x
print r
```

But I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

EDIT: If I change the first guess from `np.array([0+0j,0+0j])` to `np.array([0,0])` the function runs but I get the wrong answer (a real one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `leastsq()` can only accept real numbers, you need to use `.view()` method to convert between real array and complex array.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def cost_cpl(x, A, b):
    return (np.dot(A, x.view(np.complex128)) - b).view(np.double)

A = np.array([[1,1],[2j,0]],dtype=np.complex128)
b = np.array([1+3j,-2+2j],dtype=np.complex128)
init = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
x, r = leastsq(cost_cpl, init, args=(A, b))
print(x.view(np.complex128))
```

output:

```
array([  1.00000000e+00+1.j,   4.96506831e-16+2.j])
```